# Could I specify a particular parser rule to skip blanks?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, dsl

g4:

```
WS: [\r\n \t] -> skip;
```

It means skip all the blanks.But in some particular situations,I just need a few rules to skip blanks when analyze.

How could I specify a particular parser rule to skip blanks?Thanks for your comment.

I update the quesetions:

g4:

```
WS: [\r\n \t] -> skip;
String:[a-zA-Z]+;

stringline:'"' String '"';
```

myText:

```
"aaaa bbbb"
```

As you see,I need to recgonize "aaaa bbb" as a "stringline" under skipping blanks,how could I?

Comment: In general, Mike is right. However, there might be something possible with lexical modes. But you'll need to give an actual example of your problem.

Comment: Why not create a lexer rule with quotes: `String : '"' ~[\r\n"]* '"';` ?

Comment: String : '"' ~[\r\n"]* '"';WS: [\r\n \t] -> skip;    it seems conflict.

Comment: Oh..I get it.I have a wrong cognition of the theory before.thanks for your comment ,Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parser and lexer are independent. You cannot direct your lexer from the parser. So either you skip all whitespaces or you don't and have to handle them explicitly in every rule (lexer + parser).

Maybe it would be better to think about your solution, if it really requires such special space handling etc. and e.g. redefine the language that you wanna parse (if you are in the position to do that)?

**Update:**

From you change in your question it appears as if you are asking how to keep spaces in strings, which is why Bart suggested to create a specific lexer rule that includes both the outer quotes and possible whitespaces in it. However, you should move your WS rule to a position far down your grammar so that it doesn't "steal" whitespaces from other rules. Usually the WS rule is one of the last rules in a lexer grammar (because order matters in a grammar file).

Comment: Oh...I see...Thanks for your suggestions ,Mike

Comment: Em...Do you have a C++ rules file,could you provide me a copy of that?

Comment: What is a C++ rules file? If you wanna see examples of ANTLR lexer grammars then look in the grammar repository: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4. For the answer as such: you have to klick the check mark on the left of the answer in order to accept it.

Comment: I klicked the up arrow on the left of your comment.Including the answers before(I promised).

Comment: Not the arrow, I mean the check mark below the voting display.